# Is there a way to create a 2D list from 2 1D numpy arrays?

Tags: python

I made a function that, based on some conditions, creates a 2D list of numpy arrays from 2 1D numpy arrays. I would like to know if there's a way to simplify it or to make it more efficient, maybe by not having so many if statements or by vectorizing the for loops. The code looks like this:

```
def f(xaxis, yaxis, z_value, nprop, xidx, yidx, crange, coord) -> list:

    x = range(len(crange[xidx]))
    y = range(len(crange[yidx]))

    if xaxis == coord[0] and yaxis == coord[1]:
        return [[np.array([nprop, crange[0][i], crange[1][j], z_value], dtype=np.float64) for j in y] for i in x]
    elif xaxis == coord[1] and yaxis == coord[0]:
        return [[np.array([nprop, crange[0][j], crange[1][i], z_value], dtype=np.float64) for j in y] for i in x]
    elif xaxis == coord[0] and yaxis == coord[2]:
        return [[np.array([nprop, crange[0][i], z_value, crange[2][j]], dtype=np.float64) for j in y] for i in x]
    elif xaxis == coord[2] and yaxis == coord[0]:
        return [[np.array([nprop, crange[0][j], z_value, crange[2][i]], dtype=np.float64) for j in y] for i in x]
    elif xaxis == coord[1] and yaxis == coord[2]:
        return [[np.array([nprop, z_value, crange[1][i], crange[2][j]], dtype=np.float64) for j in y] for i in x]
    elif xaxis == coord[2] and yaxis == coord[1]:
        return [[np.array([nprop, z_value, crange[1][j], crange[2][i]], dtype=np.float64) for j in y] for i in x]
```

xaxis, yaxis are strings, coord is a tuple of strings, crange is a tuple of numpy arrays, z_value is a float, nprop, xidx and yidx are integers.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

**Update**

Let's say that the inputs look like this:

```
coord = ["x1", "x2", "x3"]
coord = np.array(coord)
xaxis = "x1"
yaxis = "x2"
xidx = 0
yidx = 1
c1 = np.random.rand(3)
c2 = np.random.rand(4)
c3 = np.random.rand(3)
crange = (c1, c2, c3)
z_value = 3.5
nprop = 4
```

Then I expect a 2D list (nested lists) of numpy arrays, like the following:

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsn5A.png)

The values of xaxis and yaxis are user's input, there are only three options (that's why there are six if statements)

Hope this update helps, thanks.

Comment: would be awesome to give some inputs and expected outputs - the more minimal the better. When things look like copy and paste, there are usually ways to simplify, but hard to think it through with what you have.

Comment: Also describing the logic behind what you expect would hepl a lot giving you solutions

Comment: fyi I updated my question to include some of these details

Comment: It doesn't make sense to nest Numpy arrays. They aren't good for storing objects, only raw numbers; and they have their own way of being "multi-dimensional".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I didn't know this, should I use tuples instead? The reason I'm making a matrix of "points" is because I need it for interpolation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refactor your function to

```py
def f(xaxis, yaxis, z_value, nprop, xidx, yidx) -> list:
    cx, cy, cz = coord
    x = range(len(crange[xidx]))
    y = range(len(crange[yidx]))
    
    matrix = []
    for i in x:
        row = []
        for j in y:
            a = crange[0][i] if xaxis == cx else crange[0][j] if yaxis == cx else z_value
            b = crange[1][i] if xaxis == cy else crange[1][j] if yaxis == cy else z_value
            c = crange[2][i] if xaxis == cz else crange[2][j] if yaxis == cz else z_value
            row.append(np.array([nprop, a, b, c], dtype=np.float64))

        matrix.append(row)
        
    return matrix
```

Note these three conditions:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Assuming `cx = coords[0]`, `cy = coords[1]` and `cz = coords[2]`, these conditions can be refactored as

[image]

---

Now, look at these another three conditions:

[image]

[image]

[image]

These conditions can be refactored as

[image]

---

Finally, the remaining values are only `z_value`s, so put it in the `else` clause.

---

Refactoring `cx`, `cy` and `cz` back to `coord`:

```py
def f(xaxis, yaxis, z_value, nprop, xidx, yidx) -> list:
    x = range(len(crange[xidx]))
    y = range(len(crange[yidx]))
    
    matrix = []
    for i in x:
        row = []
        for j in y:
            a = crange[0][i] if xaxis == coord[0] else crange[0][j] if yaxis == coord[0] else z_value
            b = crange[1][i] if xaxis == coord[1] else crange[1][j] if yaxis == coord[1] else z_value
            c = crange[2][i] if xaxis == coord[2] else crange[2][j] if yaxis == coord[2] else z_value
            row.append(np.array([nprop, a, b, c], dtype=np.float64))

        matrix.append(row)
        
    return matrix
```

Since only indices are changing between `a`, `b` and `c`, we can now replace it to a loop:

```py
def f(xaxis, yaxis, z_value, nprop, xidx, yidx) -> list:
    x = range(len(crange[xidx]))
    y = range(len(crange[yidx]))
    
    matrix = []
    for i in x:
        row = []
        for j in y:
            inner = [nprop]
            for z in range(3):
                inner.append(crange[z][i] if xaxis == coord[z] else \
                                crange[z][j] if yaxis == coord[z] else z_value)

            row.append(np.array(inner, dtype=np.float64))

        matrix.append(row)
        
    return matrix
```